# Can't mass-assign protected attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes, mass-assignment

Updating the code formatting for better viewing.

Folks,

I have been looking at this for sometime but I don't understand what could be messing up here. I am using Devise.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :addresses
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses

  # Other stuff here
end

class Address < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user

  validates_presence_of :zip #:street_address1,
```

end

> -------------------- log output begin ------------------------------
>
> Started POST "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at
>   2011-05-28 11:43:27 -0700   Processing
>   by RegistrationsController#create as
>   HTML   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"√",
>   "authenticity_token"=>"CEmdqlsmdYa6Jq0iIf5KAxxISsUCREIrFNXWkP80nhk=",
>   "user"=>{"email"=>"a2@gmail.com",
>   "password"=>"[FILT ERED]",
>   "addresses_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"street_address1"=>"234
>   Pitkin Ct.", "zip"=>"12456"}}},
>   "commit"=>"Sign up"} WARNING: Can't
>   mass-assign protected attributes:
>   addresses_attributes   SQL (0.0ms) 
>   BEGIN   SQL (164.0ms)  SHOW TABLES
>   User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT `users`.`id`
>   FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.`email` =
>   BINARY 'a2@gmail.com') LIMIT 1   SQL
>   (1.0ms)  ROLLBACK
>
> -------------------- log output end ------------------------------

The zip is present in the data posted and the posted data seems to be formatted properly. On the web page form I am getting the error that "Addresses zip can't be blank". I have dug around for what causes the "Can't mass-assign protected attributes" warning but haven't found anything that will help me.

Thanks for your thoughts and pointers.

-S

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Have a look here and learn :)

http://railscasts.com/episodes/26-hackers-love-mass-assignment

---

Edit:

Having `accepts_nested_attributes_for`in User model enables you to send the data to the Address model.

Then, in the Address model, you have to set the requested `attr_accessible`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @apneadiving. I looked through the railscasts episode and it confirms my understanding of the attr_accessible. I opened it up in my Address model (by taking out attr_accessible) so I won't have any problems. I added it back in "attr_accessible :street_address1, :zip, :address_attributes" but still get the same error. I have done this in the past and have never had to declare attr_accessible on the :nestedclass_attributes  - I am wondering devise somehow does something on the backside that causes this problem.

Comment: Tried both "attr_accessible :address_attributes" and "attr_accessible :addresses_attributes"

Comment: in your User model: `attr_accessible : addresses_attributes`, in your Adress model: `attr_accessible :zip, :street_address_1`

Comment: Indeed, Devise sets some attr_acessible in your User model, you have to keep them and add the other you need.

Comment: I tried adding them with "attr_accessible :street_address1, :zip, :addresses_attributes" but that doesn't help. Any thoughts on what I can do here? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @apneadiving. I added "attr_accessible : addresses_attributes" to the User model instead of the Address model where I was adding and that seems to work!

Comment: @apneadiving - is the sarcasm necessary? couldn't you be gracious about providing help? and I don't think adding a smiley face makes it ok.

Comment: @pingu very pleased to hear your opinion when it comes to a problem I solved. Dont be paranoid, you waste your energy

Answer (score 11):

Inside of `SpecificModel` (**appfolder/app/model/specific_model.rb**)

Try using

`attr_accessible :addresses_attributes, :another_attribute_to_make_mass_assignable, :another_attribute, etc.`

Comment: Tried   attr_accessible :street_address1, :zip, :address_attributes but get the same error.

Answer (score 6):

Nowadays (April 2013) you should start to use https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters

Answer (score 3):

Just include the **datafield** in the model as mentioned below

```
attr_accessible :addresses_attributes
```